# R - Mean of n element on list

Tags: r, list, mean

I have an object q, wich is a list with l entries, each with n values. How do I get the mean of all the elements in position n?

```
>q
[[1]]
 [1] 1 2 3 4
[[2]]
 [1] 2 3 4 5
```

Expected result:

```
1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try `rbind`-ing your list into a `matrix` and then taking the `mean` of columns:

```
colMeans(do.call(rbind, q))
#[1] 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5
```

**data:**

```
q <- list(1:4, 2:5)
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: or this `rowMeans(simplify2array(l1))` maybe

Comment: @sotos maybe, didn't know of the simplify2array function. Anyway, `rowMeans(do.call(cbind, q))` works of course identically, I guess this is more or less what `simplify2array` does for the `cbind` part)

Comment: Yeah. I run into `simplyfy2array` recently and thought to showcase it :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`+`, q)/length(q)
#[1] 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5
```

#### data

```
q <- list(1:4, 2:5)
```

Comment: Both work, but I think @Cath answer is more readable! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @DiogoSantos  That is right and if there are NA elements, Cath's answer will be more useable

Comment: What is the difference between `Reduce(...` and `do.call(...` ? At least here it gives the same result